# PMD violation :the method has cyclomatic complexity 10. What is the alternative or is it fine?

Tags: java

Please suggest any better alternatives or what can be done to improve this code ?

```
private SubscriptionOption mapSubscriptionOption(final SubscriptionType subscriptionType,
                                                 final SubscriptionInfo subscriptionInfo) {
    final boolean isSubscriptionLabelFeatureEnabled = featureService.isFeatureEnabled(SUBSCRIPTION_LABEL_FEATURE);
    switch (subscriptionType) {
        case MOBILE:
            return routingMapper.mapMobileSubscriptionOption((MobileSubscriptionInfo) subscriptionInfo, isSubscriptionLabelFeatureEnabled);
        case LTE:
            return routingMapper.mapLteSubscriptionOption((MobileSubscriptionInfo) subscriptionInfo, isSubscriptionLabelFeatureEnabled);
        case DSL:
            return routingMapper.mapDslSubscriptionOption((DslSubscriptionInfo) subscriptionInfo);
        case EARLY_DSL:
            return routingMapper.mapEarlyDslSubscriptionOption((EarlyDslSubscriptionInfo) subscriptionInfo);
        case EARLY_MOBILE:
            return routingMapper.mapEarlyMobileSubscriptionOption((EarlyMobileSubscriptionInfo) subscriptionInfo);
        case HWO:
            return routingMapper.mapHwoSubscriptionOption((HwoSubscriptionInfo) subscriptionInfo);
        case AOL:
            return routingMapper.mapAolSubscriptionOption((AolSubscriptionInfo) subscriptionInfo);
        case FMS:
            return routingMapper.mapFmsSubscriptionOption((FmsSubscriptionInfo) subscriptionInfo);
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("subscription type not handled: " + subscriptionType);
    }
}
```

Comment: A first option would be to properly format it. As you are new we'll do it for you but please take a [tour] and  read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

The code itself looks ok. One thing you *could* do is use a `Map<SubscriptionType, Function<SubscriptionInfo, SubscriptionOption>>`, do a lookup of the function by type and execute it:

```
Map<SubscriptionType, Function<SubscriptionInfo, SubscriptionOption>> mappers = ...;
mappers.put(MOBILE, info -> routingMapper.mapMobileSubscriptionOption((MobileSubscriptionInfo) info, featureService.isFeatureEnabled(SUBSCRIPTION_LABEL_FEATURE)));
mappers.put(DSL, info -> routingMapper.mapDslSubscriptionOption((DslSubscriptionInfo) info));
etc.
```

Then use it like this:

```
//note: you might want to do some null checks etc.
return mappers.get(subscriptionType).apply(subscriptionInfo);
```

This wouldn't necessarily make the code easier to read though but it might be more flexible, e.g. you could change it so that new mappers are picked up automatically or you could override a mapper if needed.